# What's the correct future form?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Given the following sentence:

> Next month, Maggie ______(meet) her sister in Japan.

Which one of these, "is meeting" and "is going to meet" is the suitable future form?

Comment: Several different verb forms work here. *Is meeting, is going to meet, will meet, will be meeting...*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between ways to express future actions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57053/) and ["The train will leave" vs. "is going to leave" vs. "leaves" vs. "is leaving"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/59292). Also related: [Simple Present for Future Actions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55686/), [Present tense for future events](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29141/), [What tense should be used here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58316/), and a whole bunch of others. Just search the site.

Comment: This question has multiple duplicates on [English.se] It should be duped to one of those rather than migrated here

Comment: Hello @Guilherme  We do already have a good answer here to your question so I've linked to that answer for you.  Hope this helps.